Prove inequality $\int_\limits{a}^b \max(f(x),g(x))\mathrm dx\le\frac{2\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}$
Let $0 < a < b$, $K$ a set of non-negative non-increasing functions on $[a,b]$ that:
$$f(a)=bf(b)$$
$$\int_\limits{a}^bf(x)\mathrm dx=1$$
Prove that for any $f$ and $g$ from $K$
$$\int_\limits{a}^b \max(f(x),g(x))\mathrm dx\le\frac{2\sqrt{b}}{\sqrt{a}+\sqrt{b}}$$
$$------------------------$$
I've found that
$$\int_\limits{a}^b\max(f(x),g(x))\mathrm dx=S+2x=1+x,$$
where $S$ - common square of $\int_\limits{a}^bf(x)\mathrm dx$ and $\int_\limits{a}^bg(x)\mathrm dx$, $x$ - square of $\int_\limits{a}^bf(x)\mathrm dx-S$ (equal to the same for $g(x)$). So I want
$$x\le\frac{\sqrt{b}-\sqrt{a}}{\sqrt{b}+\sqrt{a}}.$$
Please help me :)
